Why Angular 17 SSR cannot render data from api on server side
Create a project with angular v17 and SSR
In my app.component.ts i retrieve list of products from my api.
constructor(    
    private product: ProductService
  ) {
    this.product.getProductos().subscribe(p => {
      this.productos = p;      
    });
  }

In my app.component.html i display the list of products
  <li *ngFor="let producto of productos">
          {{ producto.nombre }} - {{ producto.precio  }}
   </li>

When I visit the url, in the first network request where the server-side rendered html document is loaded, the products obtained from the api are not displayed.
I have tried forcing the call server side
 constructor(
    private product: ProductService,
    @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
  ) {
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
      this.product.getProductos().subscribe(p => {
        this.productos = p;
      });
    }

My app.config
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideClientHydration(
      withNoHttpTransferCache()     
    ),
    provideHttpClient(
      withFetch()
    )
  ]
};

I need to render that data on the server side to optimize the website's SEO.
If anyone has run into this problem of trying to render dynamic data server-side and solved it, I would appreciate a response.

Hi Megatone, I have the same issue. did you find a fix ?

You have configured client hydration withNoHttpTransferCache. According to the docs, this is what it does:

Disables HTTP transfer cache.
Effectively causes HTTP requests to be performed twice:
once on the server and other one on the browser.

Apparently, this is not what you want. So simply remove withNoHttpTransferCache(), and the request won't be done in the browser.
Or, if you want to configure the caching, use withHttpTransferCacheOptions.

I had the same problem here. The reason was there was an error on the server side build (in my case with window object which is not available on the server) and for that reason the api data was not injected into html. Strange, but you should look into that.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
